# How long until enemies respawn in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm attempting to complete the "Clothes Make The Man" mission in Eridium Blight, I've gotten the shirt and the hat, but I've killed pretty much everyone in the mission area without finding the pants.

Is it possible to wait for the enemies to respawn? How long would it take? I'd rather not have to exit the game and restart just to finish this mission.

Comment: I had the same problem, pretty sure I fast travelled, did another quest then came back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for actual respawn length it seems fairly long, maybe 20 minutes, need to leave the area.

But to solve your problem, return to main menu and load your save game. All enemies (respawnable bosses included) will be back. Highly useful for farming.

If you WANT enemies to respawn you should never be waiting for the respawn timer. It takes far, far less time to exit and restart than to wait for any in-game timers.

Comment: Returning to main menu is enough for that to work. No need to close the .exe

Comment: @TonySniper thanks, thought so, but it's been a while since I farmed.

Answer (score 0):

When I was playing I noticed that in general leaving an area is the best way to get things to respawn, however this did not always work. If you really don't want to leave the game, I would recommend just wandering around doing other things for a while and coming back.

If the mobs haven't respawned, you're better off restarting the game (Note: I mean close the game and restart, not to start over from the beginning.)

Answer (score 0):

Normal enemies will respawn after you leave the area and came back. This doesn't matter for boss enemies like Doc Mercy, The Warrior, etc.

Here you must leave the game, return to the main menu and restart the game. After this, enemies and bosses will be respawned.

Answer (score 0):

Though it may be easier to leave the area and come back as mentioned, to answer your question based on an answer that was given on GameFaqs:

> The Official Brady Signature Series Borderlands 2 Strategy Guide for
>   Platform Microsoft XBOX 360 states that the enemy respawn time in a
>   cleared area is 25 minutes. Which sounds wrong to me despite being the
>   Gearbox sanctioned answer.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638784-borderlands-2/66074450/742908988)